# Sum not happening when unwrapping objects using Decorator Pattern

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, decorator

I am trying to solve this problem using the Decorator Pattern approach. I have used [this](http://www.lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/decorator-pattern-with-ruby-in-8-lines.html) and [this](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/14825364877/evaluating-alternative-decorator-implementations-in) as references. I am trying to sum up the tax applicable on an item that I have created, but I am only able to obtain the tax applied by the last un-wrapped object.

```
module SalesTaxDeco

  class Item

    attr_accessor :price

    def initialize(price)
      @price = price
    end

    def sales_tax
    end

  end

  class SalesTax

    def price
      @component.price
    end

    def initialize(component)
      @component = component
    end

    def sales_tax
      ((@component.price * 0.10)*(1/0.05).ceil)/(1/0.05)
    end
  end

  class ImportDuty

    def price
      @component.price
    end

    def initialize(component)
      @component = component
    end

    def sales_tax
      ((@component.price * 0.5)*(1/0.05).ceil)/(1/0.05)
    end
  end
end
```

I have created an item as

```
def test_imported_perfume_is_taxed
    item = Item.new 47.50
    assert_equal 7.15, SalesTax.new(ImportDuty.new(item)).sales_tax
end
```

but I am only getting 4.75 as the answer. What gives? Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImportDuty#sales_tax` is not called, because `SalesTax` does not call the underlying component's sales_tax method.

Try following:

```
class Item
  ....
  def sales_tax
    0
  end
end

class SalesTax
  ...
  def sales_tax
    @component.sales_tax + ((@component.price * 0.10)*(1/0.05).ceil)/(1/0.05)
  end
end

class ImportDuty
  ...
  def sales_tax
    @component.sales_tax + ((@component.price * 0.05)*(1/0.05).ceil)/(1/0.05)
  end
end
```

Using above code, `SalesTax.new(ImportDuty.new(Item.new 47.50)).sales_tax` yields `7.125`.